# LESS multiple import issue

Tags: css, import, less

I have the following files:

popup.less

```
.popup {background-color: black;}
.popup-arrow { ... }
```

tooltip.less

```
@import (reference) 'popup';
.tooltip { &:extend(.popup all);}
```

deps.less

```
@import 'tooltip';
@import 'popup';
```

I want to compile a CSS from deps.less, but in that CSS, the tooltip's style is on place, but I can't find anywhere any .popup style.

If I get rid of that popup import from tooltip.less, the style for .popup appears, but if I leave it as above, .popup is nowhere to find.

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `reference` keyword prevents a file from appearing in the output:

from here: http://lesscss.org/features/

> The following import directives have been implemented:
>
> reference: use a Less file but do not output it

Comment: yeah, but the `reference` is only for the tooltip.less file. I'm importing the file once again in deps.less with no `reference` keyword

Comment: You don't need to reference it unless you are building tooltip.css. It will be referenced anyway and work as expected.

Comment: What if I want to do both the operations? Let's say I have 2 mode compiler, for development and release. On release mode I use that deps.less, but in development mode I use files individualy (tooltip.css).

Comment: What compiler you are using?

Comment: It could be a bug in that compiler, that doesn't look like the expected functionality of that keyword. Have you tried another compiler?